# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, request

Here's the error Im getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Code:

```
async function postRequest(url, data){
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
  const response = await axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers, mode: "no-cors"})
  return response.data
}
```

What I tried:
I tried to add headers, and set mode to no-cors. didn't work. Also FYI, I m using react.

Edit: My this issue is resolved, i needed to use same port.
I have ran into another issue. its not posting the data to req.body. When I use postman, it is able to post and It is there in req.body but only in react its happening

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not something you set on a client. It is up to your server to decide if the origin is allowed.

Comment: The different port numbers (3000 vs 3001) tell the browser that you're making a cross-origin request. You can set up the server you have at port 3001 to respond with CORS headers to allow the 3000 site to access the resource.

Comment: What else does the error say? Cors errors usually tell you specifically what caused it to violate the policy.

Comment: @Pointy Using it on domains like from somedomainname.com to somedomainname.com also gives the same error

Comment: Yes it does. If the host name or port number are different (not IP address: the host name in the URL) then the browser insists on getting CORS information or else it won't allow a page access to the content.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks it worked, but I have another issue, its not sending any data through the post request. why is that? req.body is just {} and if I use postman to post, its not null